# Category filter IN and IN for ecommerce

Tags: php, mysql, sql, doctrine-orm

I am writing an ecommerce script but have stumbled upon a problem:
MySQL can't use `WHERE cat_id = 'software' AND attr_id IN (1,2) AND attr_id IN (3,4)` as it consider ambiguous.

So, to explain the DB logic it is like this :

`attrTitle` is the title of the `attr`. Example: "*Operating System*", "*License Type*"

`attr` holds the attribute related to the `attrTitle`. Each `product` can have multiple `attr` and every `attr` is linked by an FK to an `attrTitle`. Example of `attr` : "*Windows*", "*Linux*", "*Freeware*"

`product` is... well... products. Example: "*Microsoft Office*"

and `category` are categories... Each `product` is linked to only one category... Example: "*Office Suites*"

So, i want the user to be able to filter the products in the "*Office Suites*" category. For that, he have a menu saying:

```
[FILTERS]

*Operating System
- Windows
- Linux
- Mac

*Language
- English
- Español
```

So, suppose an user is looking for an Office suite that works in Windows *AND* is in English or Español.

The query became something like this :

```
SELECT *
FROM prd_product p0_ 
INNER JOIN cat_category c2_ 
    ON p0_.cat_id = c2_.cat_id 
LEFT JOIN prd_attr p4_ 
    ON p0_.prd_id = p4_.prd_id 
LEFT JOIN attr_attributeValue e3_ 
    ON e3_.attr_id = p4_.attr_id 
WHERE c2_.cat_friendlyUrl = 'software' 
    AND e3_.attr_id IN (4) 
    AND e3_.attr_id IN (10,11)
GROUP BY p0_.prd_id
```

But, as i said, it becomes ambiguous for MySQL as the espval_id is getting an WHERE IN clause two times, and then it returns an empty result. Could anyone give me a tip on how to solve this ?

And yes, i tested and there is a product with attr 4 and attr 10

**EDIT:** Sql Fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/be3198/1

Answer (score 1):

No its because the column `espval_id`  is on multiple table. And you are using join

You need to specify tablename explicitly as

```
tablename.colname IN (4)
AND
tablename.colname IN (10,11)
```

And why AND instead of that why not

```
tablename.colname IN (4,10,11)
```

Comment: Ops... Forgot to add that to the Stackoverflow but it is in my code.

Anyway, it still returns an empty result

Comment: empty result may be of other issue make sure that u specify the correct tablename where the values are in.

Comment: Edited the question to correct the colname ( i put the wrong colname in stackoverflow ) and added the info that it is not returning a resultset

Comment: Yes. I am 100% sure. If it only have ONE in clause, it works as expected. If it have two, it won't...

Comment: If i query for products with attr 4, it returns IDs 1,2,6,12,13. If i query for products with attr 10, it returns IDs 12,13. So, if i used two IN clauses it should return products 12 and 13 but isn't

Comment: Answer to `IN (4,10,11)` the `IN` clause makes it returns results that have ANY of those IDs. So, it would return ALL products that work for Windows OR are in English OR are in Español. I want it to returns products that work for Windows AND are English or Español

Comment: can u post table and some data in sqlfiddle.com